# Quadratic lower bound for deciding the set of palindromes

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, lower-bounds

How to prove a single tape Turing machine needs at least n squared time to decide palindrome?

This is an exercise from the "computational complexity - a modern approach" book.

Comment: What have you tried? Why are you stuck? Why submit this exercise to us rather than another one next page?

Comment: If you use your internet search capabilities, you would find many lecture notes with proofs of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

The lower bound you are after is a common application of *crossing sequences*. You can find many proofs of your lower bound on the web, for example these [lecture notes](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2008-09/W/6115/palindrome.pdf), which come up if you search for `palindromes quadratic lower bound`.